# PySpark Select top records using partitions

Tags: sorting, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large dataset on S3 saved as parquet files, partitioned by "last_update" column.

I want to take the top 10m records, order by last_update ASC.

I tried to save the attached dataframe to S3 but it just never ends.
Any other why to do it?

The weird thing is that I can kill it after 40 minutes that nothing happened, start it again (with same dataset!) and then it ends after 4 minutes...

(The top 10m can be all in the oldest partition or splitted on few of the oldest partitions)

Thanks!

```
sql_context.sql(
            """
            SELECT 
                trim(col1) as col1, 
                col2,
                col3
            FROM 
                global_temp.my_tbl
            ORDER BY last_update asc
            LIMIT {}
           """.format(args.num_of_records)
)
```

Comment: Did you miss a ")" at last in your sql? as I can see it from the question posted above.

Comment: Nope, just miscopied it, edited it